# How can I convert coordinate in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates

I already tried to google it but I couldn't find anything ...

I created tkinter canvas with width 800, height 600
apparently, the left upside will be (0,0) 
I want to change left downside to (0,0) 
How can I do this???

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the coordinate system of the canvas. You can scroll the canvas so that 0,0 is in the bottom left, but the y coordinates will be negative going up.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you have to define your own function. Such:

```
def conv( coordinatePair ):
    return { "x":coordinatePair["x"], "y":canvas.height-coordinatePair["y"]}
```

Where `coordinatePair` is a dictionary. That function will take your coordinate, flip the y, and return a new coordinate dictionary.